# The amount of time malloc allocated memory can be used for?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory-management, malloc

I'm abit curious on time limitations for using dynamically allocated memory. Say, for a system that is expected to run for weeks at a time, would it be safe to initially malloc memory for certain use and continually reuse this malloc'd memory over extended time periods?

Is there any specification for re-malloc'ing memory?

Comment: This looks trivial, so what am I missing?

Comment: What do you expect to happen to the malloc`ed memory that would make it unusable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `malloc` a memory zone and never `free` it you can use as long as you wish (as as long as your system is reliable enough: hardware do fail in the long run!).

Things could be different if you `malloc` and then `free` the same memory zones (particularly if the order of `malloc` and `free` is not the same or is random). In the long run, some [memory fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_fragmentation) could happen (and you cannot help much, except by having some explicit [compaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark-compact_algorithm)).

Answer (score 2):

As long as it doesn't free it, there's no limit on how long a process can use `malloc()`ed memory.

In other words, you can allocate once and then keep using the same memory for as long as you want.

The benefits of this compared to repeatedly allocating and freeing memory are:

- It's simple.
- It's more efficient.
- It can reduce memory fragmentation.

The drawbacks are:

- It's less flexible (can't be used if the size of the allocated block needs to change).
- Having a single global block can give rise to complications around reentrancy and thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

For long running apps, employing a memory pool and making sure that you have always some memory apart from other processes can be useful

Answer (score 0):

There is no time limit how long you are allowed to keep the memory. :) However, if you don't use the memory, the OS is free to swap it out if it needs it. So if you use a large chunk of memory, the OS might swap more than is needed. When you use that memory it needs to be swapped in again.
Depending on how the OS works, the memory might not really be allocated anyway just reserved until you access it.